# Slow performance of zgrep in multiple files

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, zgrep

I have a **9.8GB** gzip file A.gz and other file i have is **79MB** B.txt which has some text in each line.
I want to grep B's text in A.gz and write to a new file.

Initially, I used this command

```
zgrep -f B.txt A.gz > C.xml
```

But this command was hanged and it created an empty C.xml for very long time.

Then after googling I came to know that because B.txt is huge it hangs when it keeps the text in buffer.

So I splitted the text file in 20000 text each

```
split -l 20000 -a 4 B.txt B
```

I created files like Baaaa, Baaab....

and then iterated over each file

```
cd B
for f in B*; do
  zgrep -f "$f" ../A.gz >> C.xml
done
```

It is very slow and still running.

Any better approach for this?

Will gunzipping the gz file will improve performance?

**Update**

I tried with -F

```
zgrep -F -f "$f" ../A.gz >> C.xml
```

this is little faster but still want other option

I have xml like

```
<root>
   <source>source1</source>
   <Id>123</Id>
   <category>ABC</category>
</root>
<root>
    <source>source2</source>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <category>XYZ</category>
</root>
```

Here id is same 123 but category is different ABC and XYZ

(Input is limited set of categories e.g ABC,DEF,GHI,JKLM,NOP)
Initially I have category as ABC and So based on the category ABC I find out its id i.e. 123 like this i keep on writing all id's that belong to these input categories to a new file i.e. B.txt(list of id's) like below

```
zgrep -E 'ABC|DEF|GHI|JKLM|NOP' A.gz | sed -n 's:.*<Id>\(.*\)</Id>.*:\1:p' | uniq > B.txt
```

later on I iterate over this id's and fetch all xmls, this way I get both xml tags with category ABC and XYZ which belongs to id 123

Comment: @Anon I have updated the question with sample xml

Comment: Assuming that your file structure really is that regular could measure how big the output of a processed version is via `zgrep '\<\(category\|Id\)>'  A.gz | wc -c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 79MByte grep "string" is going to painful to work with. Are the lines of `B.txt` really regular expressions or are they fixed identical strings? If they are fixed strings do they appear identically in `A.gz` as a whole line? How many lines in the uncompressed `A.gz` are expected to be matched by lines in `B.txt`?

### Pattern matching suggestion

If lines in `B.txt` really are regular expressions or substrings of lines in `A.gz` you may be forced to use something like [HyperScan](https://github.com/intel/hyperscan) which is designed to deal with huge regexes. If you have the disk space you could decompress `A.gz` and just let HyperScan get to work on that (you may even be able to let the shell decompress on the fly while HyperScan searches through it). Another alternative to try is [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep).

### Full line matching suggestion

If you're dealing with fixed full line strings in `B.txt` and the uncompressed `A.gz` contains a comparatively small (let's say on the order of 100MB) of matching lines you may be better served writing a program to pre-process `A.gz`:

- You could hash each line of `B.txt` and remember the hashes
- You then check if any line in the uncompressed `A.gz` hashes to the same thing as any of your previous hashes. If so you print out the line (e.g. into `C.txt`) ready for further processing
- You now do final pass where you more rigorously check each line whether each line in `B.txt` is in `C.txt` (or vice versa - depending on which file was smaller)

Some code for do the initial approximate filtering could be this:

```py
# Do a quick APPROXIMATE filter of lines in FILENEEDLES that are also in
# FILEHAYSTACK
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("usage: %s FILENEEDLES FILEHAYSTACK" % sys.argv[0])
        exit(1)

    first_filename = sys.argv[1]
    second_filename = sys.argv[2]

    line_hashes = set()

    with open(first_filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            line_hashes.add(hash(line))

    with open(second_filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            if hash(line) in line_hashes:
                sys.stdout.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example:

```
$ echo -e '1\n2\n3' > B.txt
$ echo -e '2\n3\n4\5' | gzip > A.gz
$ ./approxfilter.py B.txt <(gzip -dc A.gz) > candidates.txt
$ cat candidates.txt
2
3
```

You would now need to check candidates.txt to see if lines output EXACTLY matched those of `B.txt` (but this is hopefully a smaller and far easier problem and you could even modify the program above to do it all if the number of candidate lines is "small" and well within what can be held in memory). (The questioner later clarified in comments that they are not working with full line length strings so this approach won't work)

Comment: B.txt has fixed identical strings, that is why later on i added -F in the grep command. And I am expecting 2086446 lines to be matched lines

Comment: Sorry, my mistake...B.txt has 1\n2\n3 content but A.gz has xml tags, each nested xml which has <Id>2</Id> tag. And I am grepping this <Id> tag and fetching the xml

Comment: @happy Argh. I think your next best bet is to try and think of ways to cut down `A.gz` before you have to search it. For example, do all the lines you're interested in within `A.gz` all contain some tag not seen in other lines? If so how much smaller does that make what you have to search through?

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt would very likely be improved by unzipping, otherwise each iteration of the loop will have the full unzipping overhead — unzipping beforehand will mean you only have that overhead one time.

If that is still not fast enough, you could try multi threading it as well (assumes unzipped A).

```
find B -type f -name 'B*' -print0 \
  | xargs -0 -t -n1 -P8 \
  grep -f {} A >> C.xml
```

This example should run 8 processes simultaneously, you might need to tune this value depending on how many processors/cores you have.

I’m not sure what sort of results you’re expecting speed wise; frankly, it sounds like you are giving it a lot of work to do, and lots of work takes time.

Comment: it goes out of memory when i try to unzip it as it contains 400-600gb data..What if I split this gzip file into smaller ones?

Comment: Splitting the gz as it is will not yield positive results due to the headers it will contain. You would have to decompress the file and split the raw text, and recompress. But I’m not sure if this would improve your lot.

Answer (score 1):

`zgrep` is just a shell script wrapper for `grep`. It simply runs whatever `grep` you have installed on your system and uses `gzip` to decompress the input file.

If you were using GNU grep version 3.5 or 3.6, there is  bug recently uncovered which seems to slow down processing of the pattern file as you described with extreme performance degradation.

The bug example pattern file in the release notes of grep 3.7 is about 48 Mb worth of patterns, so size should not be a problem as far as i can see.

https://www.theregister.com/2021/08/16/gnu_grep_37/

Comment: OK @terdon, thank you for trying to improve my terse answer. `Zgrep` is an interesting shell script, that is why adding .sh to the name still refers to the same application. It may come from `gzip` package or FreeBSD `grep` source itself. However the problem could be grep itself. Grep should not take more than a dozen seconds to complete compiling his pattern file and the described bug affects that precisely. He tries to fix slow processing of his pattern file by splitting it and then running a grep for loop, which is but a desperate approach.What is his grep version? IDK

Comment: Gotcha. I thought you were referring to some other tool called `zrep.sh`. I knew zgrep was a wrapper but had never seen it with an `sh` extension so that threw me. I edited to clarify. Thanks!